# Typescript nodejs - Regex pattern is not working inside a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript

I'm trying to test a little regex pattern on a string array. When I use the pattern directly with test function, it works correctly. But when I use the pattern as a constant variable, it doesn't work anymore.

Can someone explain what's wrong with my code ? Or how can I correct this ?

Thanks :)

```js
const strArray = ['(', 'ATT1', 'VARCHAR2', ')'];

const testingWord = (pString: string) => /^[^;() ]+$/g.test(pString);
strArray.map((word) => {
   console.log(word, testingWord(word));
});
// RESULT
// (        false
// ATT1     true
// VARCHAR2 true
// )        false

const PATTERN_WORD = /^[^;() ]+$/g;
const test = (pString: string) => PATTERN_WORD.test(pString);
strArray.map((word) => {
   console.log(word, testingWord(word));
});

// RESULT
// (        false
// ATT1     true
// VARCHAR2 false  <-- this should be true
// )        false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just discovered why using the `g` flag in regexes can be problematic.

The `RegExp` object has a property - [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex). Which is set when the object is used to `match` (or `test`) a string if the `y` or `g` flags are used.

This property is used when determining where to start matching, so if it isn't `0`, your regex might miss some properties.

Since you are only using this regex with `.test`, get rid of the `g` flag. It won't change the behavior of the regex.

```
const PATTERN_WORD = /^[^;() ]+$/; // <-- here
const test = (pString: string) => PATTERN_WORD.test(pString);
strArray.map((word) => {
   console.log(word, testingWord(word));
});
```